# Using a tree in python to get values

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, tree, return-value

So I am trying to create a Tree using Python to be able to try and read a text file, which has repeating quantities within the file, and try to create a tree out of these values and return the sentences with the Top 3 values (Explained in more detail below).

First of all I searched on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) on how a tree is created and have also seen previous examples on stackoverflow like: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499782/how-do-i-classify-this-value-using-a-decision-tree). and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824232/getting-a-tables-values-into-a-tree). However I have only been able to do this so far as code goes:

```
import fileinput

setPhrasesTree = 0


class Branch():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value

class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.found = False

    #lessThan function needed to compare strings
    def lessThan(self, a, b):    
        if len(a) < len(b):
            loopCount = len(a)
        else:
            loopCount = len(b)        
        for pos in range(0, loopCount):
            if a[pos] > b[pos]:
                return False        
        return True

    def insert(self, value):
        self.root = self.insertAtBranch(self.root, value)

    def exists(self, value):
        #set the class variable found to False to assume it is not there      
        self.found = False
        self.findAtBranch(self.root, value)
        return self.found

    #Used to fine a value in a tree
    def findAtBranch(self, branch, value):        
        if branch == None:
            pass
        else:
            if branch.value == value:
                self.found = True                
            else:
                self.findAtBranch(branch.left, value)
                self.findAtBranch(branch.right, value)        

    def insertAtBranch(self, branch, value):
        if branch == None:
            return Branch(value)
        else:
            if self.lessThan(branch.value, value):
                branch.right = self.insertAtBranch(branch.right, value)            
            else:
                branch.left = self.insertAtBranch(branch.left, value)
            return branch

def loadTree(filename, treeType):

    if treeType == setPhrasesTree:
        for sentence in fileinput.input("setPhrases.txt"):
            print(sentence)
            setPhrases.insert(sentence[:-1])


def findSentenceType(sentence):

    if sentence.exists(sentence):
        return setPhrasesTree
```

Here is what text file looks like. Bare in mind that it is purposefully laid out like this and not with a quantity value next to it (file name = setPhrases.txt):

```
Hi my name is Dave.
Thank-You.
What is your name?
I have done all my homework.
What time is dinner?
What is your name?
Thank-You.
Hi my name is Dave.
What is your name?
I have done all my homework.
What is your name?
Can you bring me a drink Please?
Can you bring me a drink Please?
What is your name?
Hi my name is Dave.
What is your name?
Can you bring me a drink Please?
```

Here is what I am trying to get my code to do. I need it to recognize that the first sentence, in the file, is the starting node. And then it needs to tally up all the other sentences that are the same and add a value to that sentence and just use the tree to be able to do this. (I have originally done this in another way, however I need to use a tree to be able to tally up and do all the other stuff) Here is what I mean:
[image]

I then want to be able to return the top 3 `Phrases` with the highest frequencies. So in this case the system would return the sentences (in this order):

```
What is your name?
Hi my name is Dave.
Can you bring me a drink please?
```

Any help is much appreciated. Also thank-you for your time.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you just want to count how often each line is present in the file?  You hardly need a tree for that.

Comment: @pentadecagon True and as I have mentioned earlier I have already been able to do that. However I am required to have to do this using a tree, and I have no clue on what to do next.

Comment: A tree is required?  So this is an exercise?  Just to be sure, because you know, this problem can be solved more efficiently by using a dictionary instead of a tree, in about 20 lines of code.  If you really want a tree, then, for the tree to be useful, it probably should be some kind of [self-balancing tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), the most popular here is the [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree). This is quite a lot of work to implement on your own.

Comment: @pentadecagon Can you please show me how to do it your way but also implement a way so that the user can choose an option and it will add a score of +1 to the tally in the txt file?

Comment: What do you mean by *tally in the text file*?  What would this look like?

Comment: @pentadecagon In the text file it would look like `Hi my name is Dave., 5` And so lets imagine that Hi my name is Dave has the value/tally 5 next to it as it has been used 5 times. Every time it gets chosen the tally goes up by +1. [Here is my previous example which, I thought I knew how to do after some help but failed in actually implementing the answer in to my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368016/how-can-i-add-to-the-tally-of-a-chosen-phrase)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, an implementation using a dictionary.  Is this what you want?

```
import collections
def count_lines():
    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for line in open( "phrases.txt" ):
        d[ line.strip() ] += 1

    # we use the negative count as sort key, so the biggest ends up first
    a = sorted( d.items(), key=lambda x : -x[1] )
    for n, u in enumerate( a[:3] ):
        print( u[0], "# count=", u[1] )

count_lines()
```